# how to use the token in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

i have installed the token module, but don't know how to use it. i have searched lots of time.and don't find some tutorials of it. expect someone can make me an example to use it. especially in views module. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The token module provides a centralized API for using placeholders that are replaced by text.
To start off, I suggest reading the module [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/token) and see the [list of modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/6795) that use Token. In essence it takes a token like `[user-name]` and replaces it to *enjoylife* or whatever your username is.

You cannot use Token in Views as such. But you can use it in CCK, node body, node title etc. which, in turn, can be used in Views.

One simple example of tokens is the Pathauto module — go to /admin/build/path/pathauto and check any of the 'Node paths' suggestions.

Comment: What is the syntax or proper mechanics to use a Token in the node title? (without php) Is that possible to do in the Drupal website interface?

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but there are modules like http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle that tap into Token's power and node titles

Answer (score 1):

It would help to understand better what you're trying to accomplish with token -- it is mostly used as an API and is therefore a requirement for some really useful Drupal modules like Pathauto as Zerolab suggests.